# Client who orders directly, what do we call who outsources their work?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

Well, am working on a business project where I need to name a category, say clients, now this applies to the people who directly places an order to the company, but the company also accepts outsourced projects, so they want to maintain records for the other companies who outsource their work to them.

So what is a correct word that can be used for a comapany/individual who outsources their projects?

Comment: Is it your company that does the work in each case? There are the terms *contractor*, *prime contractor*, and *sub-contractor,* where all these parties are contractors performing work on the program but the sub-contractors perform work for the prime, and the prime is responsible to the customer.  Are you trying to name the prime contractor's relationship with respect to the sub's?  That is still just a customer-contractor relationship.

Comment: @Jim Its my own, I am a web developer, so say I get outsourced projects from individuals, as well as companies..

Comment: They are both *customers/clients* to you.  Maybe there's a need to differentiate between *individual* clients and *corporate* clients?

Comment: @Jim well, that can be fine, but I was expecting some term which we can define the outsourced person in more solid way... but seeing your reputation seems like I won't get any relevant word for this :)

Comment: You never know.  There are lots of people on this site smarter than me.

Comment: @Jim will wait for someone to answer, but anyways seeing your profile, you are smart, so I really don't expect much now... anyways thank you :)

Comment: Which party in this business relationship are you trying to refer to? The client(s) or yourself?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I am the owner, I get outsourced projects from an individual or a company, the industry is web development.. and yes, clients of my own...

Comment: And to which do you want to refer? For example, you might be called a "resource" or a "vendor".

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I just want to refer the outsourced individual here with a specific word, just like we say payer and payeee... so here something like outsourcee... <-- that's just my madeup word

Comment: Again, the most common term(s) are "consultant", "resource", "vendor" or "partner". You can add descriptive terms if necessary... so, the "offshore consultant", "off-site resource", etc.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch partner or resource sounds decent to me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly based on some clarifications in the comments, you are the seller of services.  Some people buy services directly from you, others buy services from some other company and that company then employs you for part or all of the work:

> 1: (person A asks you to do work) -> (you do work) -> (person A pays you directly)

or:

> 2: (person A asks company X to do work) -> (company X asks you to do work) -> (you do work) -> (company X pays you) -> (person A pays company X)

From your perspective, person A would be the end-user in both scenarios.

In scenario 1, person A is also the client, and you are the *vendor* or the *contractor*.

In scenario 2, Company X is your client, and they are a *reseller* or *distributor* of your services; you are a *subcontractor*.  (Company X is the vendor or contractor from Person A's viewpoint.)  You may still work with the end-user directly on your portion of the job, or you may work entirely through your contacts at Company X.

Comment: Perfect, banged on, Reseller... thats what I was looking for, thanks bro :)

Comment: Yes, but reseller is typically reserved for situations in which Company X purchases goods from the manufacturer and then "resells" them with a markup to the general market or another layer of reseller.  One normally doesn't think about "reselling" custom 1-off software.